# How to change color ramp interval size in QGIS 2.12?

Tags: symbology, qgis-2.12, color-ramp

I'm working on elevation data and I'm trying to change the interval size to 50 meters in the layer's style. I created a color ramp color interpolation on the elevation layer. The values are between 8-575 meters and the number of the intervals are 12. All the values are integers.

[image]

1. The problem is that the interval size isn't 50 meters, but 51.55
   meters and I couldn't find an option to do define it at exactly 50 meters.
2. Why are the values in decimals instead of integers (50 meters)?

In arcGIS there's an option to change the interval size (also, in the same conditions- number of interval is 12) and the values are integers:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between your lowest (8) and highest (575) values, 567,  isn't divisible by 12 without a remainder. Even the Arcmap example shows an interval of 50 from 8 up to 558, and then a class of 16.851.

The only non-programmatic solution in QGIS that I can think of is to change the upper scale value to 558, create an equal interval color ramp with 12 classes, then manually add the last class of 575 (or 574.851) and define its color to match the Red-Yellow-Green color ramp.

You can manually add a class value with the + sign marked in blue

[image]

Comment: great solution!! but how you add the 575 value manually to the color ramp?

Comment: @newGIS I've modified screenshot in the question

Comment: and how can i remove the digit after the point in the labels? i want integer numbers

Comment: @newGIS that you still have to do manually, I haven't found an automated solution for the ToC. double-click the label entry and delete the decimals